# How to disable iframe right click for every website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a problem about right click for the iframe. I've done it for the default url of the IFrame but when i displayed any other webpage right click can be usable. I have used those sample codes,

```
document.onmousedown = disableclick;
    status = "Right Click Disabled";
    function disableclick(event) {
        if (event.button == 2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function disableContextMenu()
    {
        document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow.document.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };
    }
```

Here is the iframe

```
  <iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame" width="1603" height="1064" style="border:none;" src="Iframe.aspx" onload="disableContextMenu();" oncontextmenu="return false"></iframe>
```

I found the css code "pointer-events:none" but i makes the frame unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

include jquery and then apply this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#myFrame').on('contextmenu', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

thanks
hope this help

Comment: it works for the .aspx pages that i made for the page. But when I displayed any other web page it's not working. I need to do that every web page

Comment: then try to apply this on the parent div of iframe not sure but maybe works